# Pip install lxml stuck on: Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... \ (MacOS)

Tags: python, pip, lxml

When I try to install lxml for python3.10 with this code:

```
python3.10 pip3 install lxml
```

It just gets stuck on:

```
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.9.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... \
```

Anyone who knows a fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

Run pip command for lxml specific package. Later you can upgrade the package if you need the latest package.

> pip3 install lxml==version [pip3 install lxml==4.9.1]

Comment: Tried that before but didnt work, although it does work now, seems like it just needed some time. I left it and it works

Comment: FWIW, the `4.9.3` release appears to have a broken wheel for macOS, although pinning back to earlier versions works fine.